# antMatchers cannot using in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot

**antMatchers** cannot using in Spring Security.i don't i couldnt apply on that. i am using spring boot 3. can you solve my problem please

```
@Configuration
public class ProjectSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
       http.authorizeRequests()


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html) and also [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/getting-spring-security.html) the `antMatchers` was replace by `requestMatchers`.

You have to do something like it as an example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .requestMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("/api/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            );
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

Please read/check references that I gave to documentation it is going to help you to have a more understanding about it.

Comment: .requestMatchers("/api/v1/employee/employee").authenticated()  after add this url shown error was Formal varargs element type is inaccessible here

Comment: Could you update the question with what you have now after changes ?

Comment: Access to localhost was denied  when i tested the browser why

Comment: the question was about `antMatchers` and I think you should check documentation that i gave above and also go through  stackOverflow because here we have many answer of this kind of problem.